# How to create 2 rows, first with 2 and last with 3 items neatly aligned always the same position?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'd like to achieve the following layout:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+
| ItemA                                    ...ItemB |
| ItemC              ItemD                    ItemE |
+---------------------------------------------------+
```

ItemD should always be at the same place when several of those rows are put underneath each other. I guess I'd have to use with some kind of fixed width for ItemD?

Comment: please post the code you've tried

Answer (score 0):

there are many different ways to do it using `flex` and `table` and so on. But I personally prefer `float` method. It is a responsive design, similar to grid system of Bootstrap and cross-browser. Check out a working example in [**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zero_point/pen/oxNLbm)

**HTML**

```
<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="inside leftDiv">Item A</div>
  <div class="inside middleDiv">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="inside rightDiv">Item B</div>
</div>

<div class="row clearfix">
  <div class="inside leftDiv">Item C</div>
  <div class="inside middleDiv">Item D</div>
  <div class="inside rightDiv">Item E</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.row {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  background: #ccc;
}

.inside {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
  background: #ddd;
}

.leftDiv {
   text-align: left;
}

.middleDiv {
   text-align: center;
}
.rightDiv {
   text-align: right;
}
```

The `leftDiv`, `middleDiv`, and `rightDiv` classes are there to achieve different styling for the divs, like colors and widths and ...

Comment: Good start, thanks! The problem is that `ItemA,ItemC` should be left aligned, Only ItemD centered and `ItemB,ItemE` right aligned. `ItemB` should also add ellipses "..." when its not fitting its space.

Comment: check out updated answer and the working example. you did not say anything about ellipses. It is achievable if "ItemB" is one line text